# Why does list[0:len(list)+1:-1] return an empty list?

Tags: python, list, slice

First time using StackOverflow, apologies in-case of any issues.

---

In python,

`list[::-1]` returns the reversed list

`list[0:len(list)+1]` returns the complete list

### So why `list[0:len(list)+1:-1]` returns an empty list?

---

Further, for a list `l= [0,1,2,3,4,5]`, if I want like `[4,3,2]`:

Trying `l[2:5:-1]`, returns an empty list. But `l[2:5][::-1]` works.

---

Can anyone explain why this is happening? Or what is python actually doing when we slice a list, with a value for step?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1):

`some_list[start:stop:step]` means give me elements starting at `start` and incrementing by `step` until you hit `stop`.

Well, if you start at 0 and increment by -1, you never actually reach the stop.

Comment: Thank you for answering, it cleared things up but had a follow-up question. 

For ```l= [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]```, why does ```l[0:-6:-1]``` return an empty string? Since it does reach the stop value